# How to use method recover_last_checkpoints of tf.train.Saver()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The documentation writes that a list of checkpoint paths should be passed to it, but how to get the list? By hard coding? No, it's a silly practice. By parsing the protocol buffer file (a file named as `checkpoint` in your model directory)? But tensorflow does not implement a parser, does it? So do I have to implement one by myself? **Do you have a good practice to get the checkpoint paths list?**

I raise this question because these days I am troubled by one thing. As you know, a days-long training may crash for some reason, and I have to recover it from the latest checkpoint. Recovering training is easy, since I just need to write the following code:

```
restorer = tf.train.Saver()
restorer.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint)
```

I can hard code `latest_checkpoint`, or somewhat wiser, use `tf.train.latest_checkpoint()`.

However, a problem arises after I recover the training. Those old checkpoints files that are created before crash are left there. The Saver only manages the checkpoint files created in one run. I hope it could also manage the previously created checkpoints files so they would be automatically deleted, and I don't have to manually delete them every time. I think such repeating work is really silly.

Then I find the `recover_last_checkpoints` method in class `tf.train.Saver()`, which allows Saver to manage old checkpoints. But it's not handy to use. So is there any good solution?

Comment: How about `saver.recover_last_checkpoints(tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(your_checkpoint_dir).all_model_checkpoint_paths)` ?

Comment: Oh, you do solve my problem man! How did you find out that? The official API reference does not introduce the `CheckpointState` class at all! :\

Comment: I found it by digging in the source code, they use it in `tf.train.latest_checkpoint()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [@isarandi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1946465/isarandi) in a comment, the easiest way is to first recover all checkpoint paths using `get_checkpoint_state‌` followed by `all_model_checkpoi‌​nt_paths`, which is basically an undocumented feature. You can then restore your latest state as such:

```
states = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state‌​(your_checkpoint_dir‌​)
checkpoint_paths = states.all_model_checkpoi‌​nt_paths
saver.recover_last_checkpoints(checkpoint_paths)
```